# How to run an executable from any directory in terminal by setting path?

Tags: environment-variables, paths, execute-command

The executable file name is `julia`. This executable is located at `/home/siva/juliapro/julia/bin`.

I have set the path to this directory, but still, if I enter `julia` in the terminal, it says `command julia is not found`.
However, if I navigate to the folder `/home/siva/juliapro/julia/bin` and type `./julia`, I am able to run without any issues.

How to run `julia` from any directory in the terminal?

Comment: Can you execute the command `echo $PATH` and show us the results?

Comment: You should show us the command you used to set the path. There may have been a typo in it.

Comment: I would just set an alias. Alias 'julia' to the binary file and reload your sources with 'source ./bash_aliases' (assuming that is where your aliases are).

Comment: sorry , my bad . it was a typo indeed , should have paid attention to the case -sensitive path .

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way to be able to run your command in the terminal from any working directory is to have it in your `~/bin` or `~/local/bin` folder, or in `/usr/local/bin` if all users need access to the command.

`~/bin` or `~/local/bin` do not exist by default. You need to create either of these folders yourself. On Ubuntu, if they exist, they automatically will be included in your PATH next time you open the terminal.

The executable you place in either of these folders can be of a different nature:

- It could be the binary itself, moved there.
- It could be a symbolic link to the actual binary

These options are only possible if the executable does not require to be in a specific folder structure (e.g. have specific folders underneath, etc.)

- It could be a wrapper script that calls the executable. That also gives the flexibility to change the working environment and working directory when launched.

I am aware that this is not the way you were considering to solve this. However, I provide this alternative solution because it is more standard and scalable. In your approach, you would need to add yet other folders to the PATH if in the future, you have other custom executables. The PATH eventually could become so large that launching applications is somewhat slowed down, when the system has to cross many paths to find your executable.